# How to enumerate returned rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, enumeration

I was wondering if it would be possible to enumerate returned rows. Not according to any column content but just yielding a sequential integer index. E.g.

```
select ?, count(*) as usercount from users group by age
```

would return something along the lines:

```
1    12
2    78
3     4
4    42
```

it is for https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @benv: it's for http://odata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SilentGhost then the relevant tags may have been [tag:tsql] and [tag:dataexplorer]. But now that there is mysql and oracle answers, it's a bit late to change it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY age) AS RowNumber
        ,count(*) as usercount 
    from users 
    group by age
```

Answer (score 6):

If it's Oracle, use `rownum`.

```
SELECT SOMETABLE.*, ROWNUM RN
FROM SOMETABLE
WHERE SOMETABLE.SOMECOLUMN = :SOMEVALUE
ORDER BY SOMETABLE.SOMEOTHERCOLUMN;
```

The final answer will entirely depend on what database you're using.

Answer (score 4):

For MySql:

```
SELECT  @row := @row + 1 as row FROM anytable a, (SELECT @row := 0) r
```

Answer (score 2):

use [rownumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function available in sql server

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columnNAME) AS 'RowNumber',count(*) as usercount
    FROM users
```

Answer (score 1):

How you'd do that depends on your database server.  In SQL Server, you could use `row_number()`:

```
select  row_number() over (order by age)
,       age
,       count(*) as usercount 
from    users 
group by 
        age
order by
        age
```

But it's often easier and faster to use client side row numbers.

Comment: the `partition by age` will cause the number to rest for each `age`, and the query is grouping by age, so your row number will be 1 for every row.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to majority of other answers, and in accordance of the actual OP question, to

> enumerate returned rows (...) **NOT** according to any column content

but rather in the order of returned query, one could use a dummy ordinal variable to `ORDER BY` in an `ROW_NUMBER` function, e.g.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS row_num
```

where one could actually use anything as an argument to the `SELECT`-statement, like `SELECT 100`, `SELECT ‘A’`, `SELECT NULL`, etc..

This way, the row numbers will be enumerated in the same order the data was added to the table.

Comment: Correct parantheses: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS row_num`. P.S. This answer does not work if ORDER BY is used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

for `Mysql`

```
set @row:=0;

select @row:=@row+1 as row, a.* from table_name as a;
```